# Specify VueJS component type and properties at runtime

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to build a form using [Element.io](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US) components from a JSON object:

```
var form = [
    {tag: 'input', type: 'text', value: 123}, 
    {tag: 'select', options: [{value: 10, desc: 'ten'}]}
];
```

How can I specify the component to add to my form?

I suppose I could have a `.vue` file for each component, and pass props to it so it would return a component. But, is that the best way? Can I specify the component without having to create a file for each component in that library?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for [Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

You can add a `<component>` tag and specify the type of component using the `is` property.

Then you can use [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) to bind an object of property values to the component.

In your case (since Element.io component names appear to be the tag value prefixed with "el-"), you might do something like this:

```
<template v-for="input in form">
  <component :is="'el-' + input.tag" v-bind="input"></component>
</template>
```

Comment: Ah, nice! `+1` Thanks. Is there a way to pass a object as `props` to my compnent? Something like `<component :is="'el-' + input.tag" {...input.props}` or maybe `<component :is="'el-' + input.tag" :props="{...input.props}"`?

Comment: I wonder also how to use the _Dynamic Component_ idea with a JSON array? can I map my array with components? In React we could do `selectOptions = arr.map(opt => <some-jsx props={...opt.props}>` is there a similar logic in Vue.js?

Comment: Updated my answer to address your first question. As to your second question, the form variable being used in the template in my example is your JSON array. Using v-for is how you would map it to components.